# Lease discrepancy

Tags: lease

My landlord (New Jersey owner occupied  3 family house) gave me a new lease for$1400 and then another paper stating they were raising the rent to a total amount due per month of $400.  Which is valid?

Answer (score 1):

If your landlord gave you a signed lease, and you accepted and agreed to it, it is binding on the landlord and on you as written 9assuming it does not violate the law of your jurisdiction).

Most often a lease specifies a specific amount od rent to be paid, per month, quarter, year or other tiem period. Some leases include provisions allowing a landlord to increase or change the rent at specified times or under specified circumstances.

It would be unusual for a landlord to be able to increase the rent on a just agreed lease renewal, particularly by a large amount.

If the tenant had not accepted the renewal lease, the landlord could withdraw the offer and make a different offer.

Thew question mentions a rent of $1400 and then of an increased rent of $400 per month. That would be a total of $4800 per year, which would be a large increase from $1400 if tht was an annual figure. On the other hand $400/month total seems like a low rent currently, but this depends on the location and the details of what is being rented, neither of which is stated in the question. It would be clearer if the question said whether $1400 was per year or what tiem period it applied to.

Residential lease agreements are subject to lots of specific local laws adn regulations. These may apply and the state, county or municipality level. These vary wildly. Specific provisions may be required or forbidden. Rent increases may be limited. Times for renewals may be mandated.

It is often wise to consult local resources. In many places government or non-profit groups offer detailed advice to tenants. A local lawyer can also offer specific advice, beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: I think the most simple answer is the obvious one here and that is: the one that says $400 is a typo which should have said $1400.

Comment: @A.fm That is possible, but then it wouldn't say that there was an increase, it seems. Tenant might ask landlord what the intent here is and why.